# WP htaccess Redirect Correct But Not Working?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm currently using the Adforest theme to make a classified ads site and the user accounts default to /author/username.
I used a plugin that changes /author/ to /user/ and all worked as intended, however to view the ads on the user's page, you must link to /user/username/?type=ads.
My goal is to have /user/username/ads (or just /user/username/) silently redirect to /user/username/?type=ads, providing a pretty permalink structure.

The issue comes in when I try to make the htaccess rule to accomplish this. I have tried at least two dozen variations, however none have proved to be successful. I have checked my URL against the htaccess rules through a third party tool (https://htaccess.madewithlove.be) and ensured that each was crafted to work as intended, with the latest "working" rules down below. However, I still run into the issue of it just plain, flat-out not working. I have tried with and without the plugin I first mentioned being activated, as well as flushed my permalinks, and each time I'm brought back to the same 404 page.

Any insight into what's going on that I'm not catching would be very much appreciated!

Last Used htaccess Code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/ads$ /user/$1?type=ads [NE,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

As well as dozens of other variations:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user/$1?type=ads [L]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/$ /user/$1?type=ads [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/ads$ /user/$1?type=ads [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /user/$1?type=ads [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/$ /user/$1?type=ads [L]
...
```

For completion sake, my current htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)/ads$ /user/$1?type=ads [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The default WP rewriting at the top will rewrite everything that does not match a physically existing file or folder to its index.php already, and the `[L]` flag means processing stops at that point. It doesn’t even get to your rules afterwards.

Comment: Hi CBroe, I should have mentioned that the placement of the rule has not made an impact at all. First I placed it above, then below, and each iteration I've tried has not made a bit of difference. I've also tried removing the <IfModule> to no avail.